# Excluding and adding new attributes in copy command to OrientDB

Tags: sql, indexing, orientdb

Consider the following query:

```
insert into User from select from User where @rid = #12:0
```

Now suppose there's an attribute `User.id` which is an index

```
create index User.id on User (id) unique
```

This makes the query above complain that inserting record with the same id is impossible, since attribute `id` has a `unique` index.

**Question**: How does one copy a record with a unique id and substitute that id for a new one?

Comment: first of all try to avoid using reserve words as table name and column name

Comment: Hi @Sachu, `User` and `id` aren't reserved words in OrientDB. They have `OUser` and `@rid` for that

Comment: sorry i didnt check the db..my mistake..